# Error `Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found.` though it's there

Tags: django

I configured `urls.py` as

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
    template_name="user/password_reset_confirm.html",
),
name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

It does have a name `password_reset_confirm`,
However, the browser prompts it was not a valid pattern

```
NoReverseMatch at /user/password_reset/
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/user/password_reset/
Django Version: 1.11.13
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' not found. 'password_reset_confirm' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

apps setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #my apps
    "article",
    "user",
]
```

The project urls.py

```
# Project url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r"^$", views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^article/', include('article.urls',namespace='article')),
    url(r'^user/', include('user.urls',namespace='user')),
    # url(r'^register/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

How to handle such a problem?

Comment: The module which includes `urls.py` file should be in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Can you share your settings for `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Do you use namespace or app_name?

Comment: I used namespaces @neverwalkaloner

Comment: You should use then `namespace:password_reset_confirm` as url name.

Comment: fantastic, could you please transmit the short comment to answer. @neverwalkaloner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `namespace='user'` in project `urls.py` file you should use `namespace_value:password_reset_confirm` as urlpattern name in your code, for example in template:

```
{% url 'user:password_reset_confirm' %}
```

instead of

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' %}
```

You can find more details in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls).